# How do I redirect multiple URLs in Azure Application Gateway?

Tags: azure, redirect, azure-application-gateway

In Azure Application Gateway, is it possible to do the following redirects:

```
example.com/folder1/page1.html > newexample.com
www.example.com/folder1/page1.html > newexample.com
example2.com/folder2/page2.html > newexample.com/page2.html
```

I've added a single listener and rule for the first redirect and that is working. I've tried to add multiple rules through the Azure dashboard, but see the following error:

```
There are no unassociated listeners available. Create a new listener and then try again.
```

When I try to add another basic listener, I see:

```
This HTTP listener cannot use the same frontend port as an existing listener.
```

Also, if I change the existing rule to be redirect to another URL, it doesn't appear to update - I am redirected to the original site.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to set up vhosts in nginx and redirect the domains. It seemed much simpler than configuring the Azure Application Gateway.

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName   www.example.org.uk
    ServerAlias  example.org.uk
    Redirect 301 / https://www.newexample.com/abc/def/ghi
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you need to configure multiple site listener, refer to following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/multiple-site-overview

Comment: Please add the content to the size instead of just pasting the link, that way if the link goes down, we still have the answer to the question.